# ListView updates the entry only when the application is restarted again

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

In this application, I have a `listview` and a `sqlitedatabase`. There is a `floating action button` which on clicking displays a `dialog box` containing two `edittext` one for name and another for number. The problem is that the after clicking on the `add` option of the `dialog box` the entry is not shown on the `listview`. But when the `activity` is destroyed and `onCreate` is called again on the `activity` , the entry is shown.

I tried using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but it doesn't work. The code is shown below :

**Code**

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseManager manager;
private ListView listView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

final String[] from=new String[] {UserDatabase.NAME,UserDatabase.NUMBER};

final int[] to=new int[] {R.id.nameDisplay,R.id.phoneDisplay};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    manager = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    manager.open();
    Cursor cursor=manager.fetch();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailsActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = DetailsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            final EditText name = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogEditNmID);
            final EditText phone = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogEditPhID);

            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Add Details");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) &&
                            !TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {
                        /*adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        manager.insert(name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Added " + name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                        insertData(name.getText().toString(),phone.getText().toString());
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Empty field(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

            dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
            b.show();
            //  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

public void insertData(String fname,String phnumber){
    manager.insert(fname,phnumber);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Some of the statements are commented because I tried to get the desired result but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you insert the entries in your database, you should fetch the data again so that your list has the newest entry. So you can either modify your code to be able to add a data point to the list you are passing to the adapter or refetch the data from the database after insertions and before notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: So, after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); manager.insert(name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString());` in the `onClick`, you want me to fetch the data from database like `cursor=manager.fetch();` and then set the `listview adapter`

Comment: Before the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged. Essentially you are using a list that is passed to the adapter being used by your listview. When you insert into the database you also need to update (add the new entry in) the list that the adapter is referencing too. All this needs to be done before onNotifyDatasetChanged.
See the answer by @Michael. He explained it in good detail.

Comment: Ya, I have taken his advice and changed my code. Could you please look at it

Comment: Its incorrect. Uncomment these 2 lines from outside the onClick. This is your inital list setup
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
// listView.setAdapter(adapter);

And then insert these 3 lines after insertData in your on click.
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Not the best way but should get it to work.

Comment: Still it doesn't work. I have to restart the app to display the entries last entered.

Comment: My bad I forgot to update the cursor
Uncomment these 2 lines from outside the onClick. This is your inital list setup
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
// listView.setAdapter(adapter);

And then insert these 4 lines after insertData in your on click.
Cursor cursor=manager.fetch();
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Not the best way but should get it to work.

Comment: Just one doubt, you said that it is not the best way , why is it so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156926/discussion-between-anshul-and-pritom-mazumdar).

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple things here you have to change. Taking a look at this code:

```
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            manager.insert(name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added " + name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty field(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

1. When you click the "Add" button, right away you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. In your case, you are only supposed to call that after you have added items to `listView`, but you haven't added anything yet.
2. You insert into your database using `manager.insert(name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString());`, but you don't update `listView` with your newly added data. You need to insert that data to the database, and then also add that data to `listView`.

Now you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

I would recommend that when you want to insert into your database, create a method which will insert the data, add the new data to the `listView`, and then tell the adapter to refresh.

**Edit**

Regarding your recent edit, there's still a few things that need to be taken care of.

1. You should not have `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` in the method. You had it right the first time (in onCreate() but before the dialog builder).
2. You call `manager.insert(fname,phnumber);`, but still do not add the newly inserted data to `listView`.

Here's pseudocode for what you should have in your method:

```
public void insertData(String fname,String phnumber){
    manager.insert(fname,phnumber);
    // Code to add the data you just inserted into the manager above to `listView`.
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Remember, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` only updates `listView` if there's changes to `listView`, and as of right now you haven't added/deleted/modified `listView`.

Answer (score 1):

i have did some changes into the code please try it and let me know if it is helpful or not

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseManager manager;
private ListView listView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

final String[] from=new String[] {UserDatabase.NAME,UserDatabase.NUMBER};

final int[] to=new int[] {R.id.nameDisplay,R.id.phoneDisplay};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    manager = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    manager.open();


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailsActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = DetailsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            final EditText name = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogEditNmID);
            final EditText phone = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogEditPhID);

            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Add Details");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) &&
                            !TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        manager.insert(name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Added " + name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Cursor cursor = manager.fetch();

                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Empty field(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

            dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
            b.show();
            //  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Application crashes because of `null object reference`. You initialized `adapter` inside the `onClick` method but not before it.

Comment: i have added it into the onCreate  method, i think it should work now

Comment: Now you have initialized `cursor` inside `onClick` method. And the parameters for `simpleCursorAdapter` conatins cursor.

Comment: Just make the Cursor object as global.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use notifyDataSetChanged after insert operation. In all place where you call(try to call) notify manager data isn't change yet.